# Finding the orientation of location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, direction

I'm wondering if there's some way to find the orientation of a set of points along a line as a number (degrees from north) in ArcGIS?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Is it the azimuth you're looking for? Is it a polyline feature and the points vertices?  What program are you using to do this? Are you trying to write a python script using arcpy to do this, or are you trying to do this in arcgis pro, arcgis desktop??  What have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps this tool is what your looking for (it's available in ArcGIS pro and Desktop): https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/bearing-distance-to-line.htm